# Can i mock document.location.search in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm currently running tests in PhantomJS. I have code that requires "document.location.search" to return some specific query string parameters.

My question is, is it possible to mock this property in PhantomJS?

The only solution i have so far is to wrap "document.location.search" in some function of my own and mock that, but i'd prefer not to have to write extra functions just to make my tests work.

Comment: make the part that gets the string outside of the part that needs testing, so that you can feed it a string or default to location.search.